responsiveness issue with overlay-navbar icon
how do i change my responsiveness in overlay-navbar->ReactNavbar.min.css if i have used it by importing because i am having an issue with the icon's responsiveness which is due to a line in ReactNavbar.min.css like:
`@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .logoReactNavbar {
        width: 200% !important;
    }
}`

beacuse of this the picture gets zoomed in when screen-width decreases to 800px.
i have tried changing and overriding styles but anything did not work out
